# Error when trying to apply PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-05-05-02.sh

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches

I have just tried to apply PATCH_SUPEE-5994 however below is the message I got. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-05-05-02.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 48.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 30.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/messages.phtml.rej
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

Comment: Further to the useful answers, it would also be useful if Magento carried out a better naming convention for their patches because patch SUPEE-5994 does not apply to EE (only CE) yet the patch file name includes 'EE'. This is the case for numerous other filenames for their patches as well.

Comment: My installation was missing get.php at the Magento root folder. You can find original source files on github: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror Then click the branch button for your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a failed patch installation because a previous developer had edited get.php for some reason only he knows.

After uploading an unedited copy of the problem file(s), in your case

- app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
- downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
- downloader/template/messages.phtml

try the patch process again.

This is one of those reasons why we are told time and time again **DO NOT EDIT CORE FILES**

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. It seemed that a previous developer removed the downloader directory for securitye reasons. (in my case only downloader map was missing)

The patch first checks if he can patches everything. If not - and in this case not - the patch fails.

For PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-05-05-02.sh you can see on line 133 "exit 1" because of the fail.

So I commented line 133 to prevent exit and the patch was applied succesfully.

NOTE: in my case only the downloader map was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to install correctly the patch 5994 :

1 - `Open the patch 5994 file with textedit or notepad.`

2 - `Search for the word "downloader" in the code.`

3 - `Change the name of the directory "downloader"  with the real name on your server "downloader_fh0******".`

Example :

```
change 

downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
```

to  `downloader_fh0******/Maged/Model/Connect.php` 
    This has be`en changed recently in order to avoid someone from outside to take control of the directory`.

4 - `Save your file and upload it to your server`.

5 - `Apply the patch.`